# comparing two java lists

Tags: java, list

I want to compare each elements of two java lists together, the lists could have null elements, but if I use `.equals()` method I will get a `NullPointerExeption`. How can I avoid this? How can I improve the code ?

```
if (l1!=null && l2!=null && l1.size()==l2.size()) {  
    for (int i = 0; i <l1.size(); i++) {
        if (!l1.get(i).equals(l2.get(i))) {  
            return false;     
        }
    } 
}
return true;
```

how can I compare null elements in the lists with equal method?

Comment: Does your list contain integers?

Comment: [Objects.equals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#equals-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object-) is able to deal with null values: `if(!Objects.equals(l1.get(i), l2.get(i)))`

Comment: but i checked in the first (if statement)  l1!=null and l2!=null

Comment: Your code will return true if the two lists are different lengths. Is that your intention?

Comment: public static boolean compare (List<Integer> l1, List<Integer> l2) the lists have the typ INTEGER

Comment: [Simple way to find if two different lists contain exactly the same elements?](//stackoverflow.com/q/1075656)

Comment: I'm not alowed to use  if(!Objects.equals(l1.get(i), l2.get(i)))

Comment: Then check `l1.get(i) != null` before checking the rest of the condition

Comment: with  l1.get(i) != null   and l2.get(i)!=null  i checked but it does'nt work ! Is there anoter way to solve this problem ?

Comment: @Yasmin if you tried please [edit] your question to show your attempt so we can help you with that, because that's the correct way to solve this without using `Objects.equals`.

Answer (score 0):

If the lists may contain null elements, you will need to handle them properly when comparing the elements.

One way to handle null elements is to use the `Objects.equals(Object a, Object b)` method from the `java.util.Objects` class. This method compares two objects for equality and returns true if both objects are null or if the a.equals(b), otherwise false.

```
if (l1!=null && l2!=null && l1.size()==l2.size()) {  
    for (int i = 0; i <l1.size(); i++) {
        if (!Objects.equals(l1.get(i), l2.get(i))) {  
            return false;     
        }
    } 
}
return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
l1.get(i).equals(l2.get(i))
```

throws a `NullPointerException` only if:

- `l1` is `null`; or
- `l1.get(i)` is `null`; or
- `l2` is `null`.

You are checking if either of `l1` and `l2` are `null`, but you're not checking if `l1.get(i)` is `null`.

To fix this, use `!Objects.equals(l1.get(i), l2.get(i))`. However, if you may not use `Objects.equals`, then you have to use null-checks.

```java
!(l1.get(i) == null && l2.get(i) == null || (l1.get(i) != null && l1.get(i).equals(l2.get(i))))
```

Comment: if i write like you , there is a problem if the lists are l1 = {1, null, 3}, l2 = {1, null, 3} or l1={1,2,3}, l2={1,2,3}

Comment: @Yasmin That was a typo. Please try it again.